# Confusion with peak and RMS values when calculating the torque of an electric motor

Tags: motor, torque

For electric 3-phase motors with a efficiency of 100% (assumed here for simplicity) the following equation holds:

$$P = \omega T = 3 U I$$

where \$U\$ and \$I\$ are the phase RMS values of the voltage and current respectively (phase to neutral RMS voltage and phase current when a star connection is used). I can calculate the torque with this expression. So far so good. Now I want to use an approach which is better applicable for data from e.g. FEM analysis. The torque can also be calculated like:

$$T=\frac{N_p}{2} \vec{\Psi} \times \vec{i}$$

where \$N_p\$ is the number of poles and the 3-phase values are transformed to vectors with a power invariant transformation like:

$$\vec{a} = \sqrt{2/3} (a_a + a_b \exp(j 2 \pi /3) + a_b \exp(j 4 \pi /3))$$

as a power invariant transformation was used, the torque formula from above doesn't need another factor. At least this is how I understood it. When a symmetric 3-phase system is assumed, \$\vec{a}\$ can also be rewritten as:

$$\vec{a} = A \exp{j \omega t}$$

where \$A\$ is the RMS phase-to-phase value (if everything is assumed as ideal, hence, sinusoidal flux density and MMF distributions). But this means, that I'm combining two phase-to-phase values in the second equation but two phase values in the first equation. And like for the flux, flux density and so on, normally there isn't something like a RMS value because the iron and so on doesn't care about RMS values, it is only 'interested' in peak values. So I don't really get the connection here. It would be great if someone could give me some hints what I'm not getting here.

Comment: The torque of an electric motor is far more complicated than that. It is also nonlinear and RPM dependent. Take a look at the torque curve of a 3 phase induction motor.

Comment: Yeah sure, but like if one just want to understand the basic phenomenons it's always a good start if you regard everything as linear, ideal and in a steady state.